# Make a bezier curve control point exactly vertical

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, snapping

I've created a bezier curve and given it some depth. I'm trying to make the control point on the end point exactly up and down. I guess you could say I'm trying to align it with its local z axis.

I know I can copy and paste the x and y numbers from the center point to the extended arms, but there's got to be a faster way, right? I have 17 of these to do, so any shortcut would be appreciated.

In the picture, I've selected the control point in question. It looks vertical, but it's not *exactly* vertical (and it needs to be).

Thanks for any help you can give!

[image: almost-vertical control point]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is:

1. Select the Bezier curve and go into Edit mode.
2. Select the end point that you want to align.
3. Press Shift + S and select "Cursor to Selected" from the menu.
4. Select the control point that you want to align and press Shift + S again. and select "Selection to Cursor (Offset)" from the menu.

See if it helps
There might be other more faster ways I guess but that's one of em

Comment: That worked for me. I would also like to add a step 5. Press G, Z, and drag the handle upwards a bit. Otherwise, it sits on top of the center point.